# In how many ways can we pick a group of 3 different numbers from the group $1, 2, 3, ..., 500$ such that one number is the average of the other two?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Here's the question which I'm struggling with -

> In how many ways can we pick a group of 3 different numbers from the group
>
> $1, 2, 3, ..., 500$
>
> such that one number is the average of the other two? (The order doesn't matter)

Here's what I've done -

Choose any 3 number $x$, $y$ and $\frac{x+y}{2}$. If $x + y$ is even then $\frac{x+y}{2}$ always exists.

Case 1:

$x = y = $ even

There are 250 even numbers from 1 to 500. Every combination of $x, y$ will have a solution. Number of distinct pairs of $x, y$ is

$$\frac{250 \cdot 250 + 250}{2}=31375$$

It is necessary to add 250 because when $x = y$, the combination doesn't repeat twice.

Similarly, when $x = y = $ odd, the total is 31375.

Hence the total number of possibilities are $31375 + 31375 = 62750$.

But my textbook says that the answer is 62250. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are $\binom{250}2$ pairs of even numbers and $\binom{250}2$ pairs of odd numbers. Each of those pairs gives you one solution, and each solution is of one of those two forms. Thus, the total number of solutions is

$$2\binom{250}2=2\cdot\frac{250\cdot249}2=250\cdot249=62,250\;.$$

Your mistake was in *adding* $250$ in the numerator instead of *subtracting* it to get rid of the $x=y$ pairs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :) But then are $x = y$ pairs included in 62,250 combinations?

Comment: @AoPS: No, they’re not. The $62,250$ counts the pairs of distinct integers from $\{1,\ldots,500\}$ such that the two members of the pair have the same parity (both odd or both even).